# What are the different ways to access the content of an email in python using Imaplib.

Tags: python-3.x, email

I have been working on creating a python script to clean up my mail box, I am using Python's imaplib for the same. For this task I want to access the message contents so that I can classify if the mail is important or not. I found that to access the message objects' content body, the one suggested option is to walk through the message ; using message.walk function.
I wanted to know if there is any other way this problem can be handled ?
Why cant we access the payload content as we access the headers ; consindering both are lists.

Comment: Please provide example code for what you've tried so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: message.walk() method as described in the python official tutorials, is the only way to access the message content of any email. 
I implemented and got the results I needed. example shown below.
But I was curious to know if there was any other way the message content could be accessed.
 #python code example
 for content in msg.walk():
 print(content.get_content_type());
 if content.get_content_type() == 'multipart/alternative':
  print('the multipart content is :',content);
 elif : ....... #likewise